# Function returning the wrong value

Tags: c++, algorithm, return

This project is a homework assignment for school. The instructor has asked us to input 20 random integers then print the smallest in the list and then search the list for the first iteration of the number entered. My problem is returning the smallest number of the list. The function, shown below accepts an integer array and an integer with the size of the array. In Visual Studio, the tests for the smallest number work until the function returns the value. Instead of returning the smallest number, the function returns some kind of default value as opposed to the smallest integer. I have been staring at this code for the past two hours, any help would be appreciated.

```
int theSmallest(const int a[], int number_used)
{
    int temp = a[0];
    // Find the smallest number in array a[]
    for (int i = 0; i <= number_used; i++)
    {
        if (temp >= a[i])
        {
            temp = a[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `number_used` is the length of `a`, then you will try to access an element past the end of the array when `i == number_used`.

Comment: `i <= number_used` arrays are zero based, it should be `a < number_used`

Comment: Also you should start from `i = 1`.

Comment: Returning the smallest is trivial. Just `std::sort()` the container of values, then return the first one (assuming sorting in ascending order and assuming the container is not empty). Or just use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element). [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) could also be used.

Comment: @Jesper, Why suffer the overhead of sorting ?  A single run through is all it takes.

Comment: @Sid S - which is why I also mention `std::min_element`. I'm just trying to show that there are several simple ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Two hours spent staring at code that doesn't work is two hours wasted. You should have *tried something simpler,* like printing out the numbers in the array. That would have shown you the bug more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior because you are accessing the array `a` using an invalid index.

When an array has 20 elements, the valid indices are 0-19, not 0-20.

You are using

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number_used; i++)
```

and then accessing `a[i]` in the loop. If `number_used` is equal to 20, you are accessing `a` using and index value of 20, which is not correct.

Change that to use  `i < number_used`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_used; i++)
```

---

A minor issue is that you are using `temp >= a[i]`, which can be changed to use `temp > a[i]`. Use of `>=` in this case will work but it will do more work than necessary.

---

Here's an updated version of the function:

```
int theSmallest(const int a[], int number_used)
{
    int temp = a[0];
    // Find the smallest number in array a[]
    for (int i = 1; i < number_used; i++)
    {
        if (temp > a[i])
        {
            temp = a[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `number_used` is the size of array, code can be written as:

```
int theSmallest(const int a[], int number_used)
{
    if( a == nullptr or number_used == 0 )
        throw std::runtime_error( "invalid argument" );
    return *std::min_element( a, a + number_used );
}
```

Note: you code has issue in case `number_used` is equal to 0 or `a` pointer is passed as `nullptr`,  you may not expect that to happen but it is good idea to always validate your input (at least by assert())

Answer (score 0):

Change to `i < number_used` and I think change to `if(temp > a[i])`.

You can also start `i=1` since you made the assumption `index 0` is the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number_used; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < number_used; i++)
```